# what is the difference between grouping similar methods as class static methods or object members?

Tags: javascript, class, object, static, static-methods

In javascript, I have these two approaches to group similar methods:

first approach:

```js
class GroupedMethodsWithClass {
  static a = () => {
    console.log("a")
  };

  static b = () => {
    console.log("b")
  }
}
```

and the second one:

```js
const GroupedMethodsWithObject = {
  a() {
    console.log("a");
  },
  b() {
    console.log("b");
  },
}
```

Right now I only know that I have the [class static initialization block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_static_initialization_blocks) option with first approach:

```js
class GroupedMethodsWithClass {
  static a = () => {
      console.log("a")
  }
  static b = () => {
      console.log("b")
  }
  static {
    console.log('Class static initialization block called');
  }
}
```

But does anyone knows what are the real differences between these two approaches?

Comment: Why would you use either of these over functions?

Comment: Why are you using arrow functions in one code but method definitions in the other?

Comment: You should not use `class` if your class will never be instantiated and has only static methods.